# Delete files type in directory java

Tags: java, file, error-handling, directory, delete-file

How can I delete the file in the directory / folder

I am using this code:

```
private static final String FILE_DIR = "data\\session";
private static final String FILE_TEXT_EXT = ".cache";

private void DeleteCache(String folder, String ext){
        GenericExtFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(ext);
        File dir = new File(folder);
         File fileDelete;
        String[] list = dir.list(filter);
        for(String file : list){
            String temp = new StringBuffer().append(File.separator).append(file).toString();
            fileDelete = new File(temp);
            boolean isDelete=fileDelete.delete();
            System.out.println("File : "+temp+"is Delete : "+isDelete);
        }

        if(list.length == 0 ) return;
    }
    public class GenericExtFilter implements FilenameFilter{
        private String ext;
        public GenericExtFilter(String ext){
            this.ext=ext;
        }
        public boolean accept (File dir, String name){
            return (name.endsWith(ext));
        }
    }
```

but why yes if, cache do not want to be removed
example error

> File : \31052012-TPBSDERG.cache -is Delete : false

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the file does not exist.

Try using....

```
File[] list = dir.listFiles(filter);
```

Instead

**UPDATE**

There are many reasons why a file may not be deleted.  The actual process is depended on the underlying OS, but the most common reasons are, the file is open by another process (or your program), you don't have the correct permissions to delete the file and/or the file doesn't exist.

There are a number of interesting issues with your code...

```
String temp = new StringBuffer().append(File.separator).append(file).toString();
```

This is appending a file separator to the file which now says, "look for the file in the root directory of the current drive", which is (probably) not where the file exists.

For example;

```
File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
String[] list = dir.list(filter);
for(String file : list){
    String temp = new StringBuffer().append(File.separator).append(file).toString();
    System.out.println(temp + " - " + new File(temp).exists());
}
```

This outputs something like...

```
/.bash_history - false
/.CFUserTextEncoding - false
/.config - false
/.cups - false
```

Which is obviously wrong, these files don't live in the root folder

Equally if I do;

```
File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
String[] list = dir.list(filter);
for(String file : list){
    System.out.println(file + " - " + new File(file).exists());
}
```

This outputs something like...

```
.bash_history - false
.CFUserTextEncoding - false
.config - false
.cups - false
```

This is equally as useless, as these files don't exist in the current execution location either...

Now, however, if I do something like...

```
String folder = System.getProperty("user.home");
File[] list = new File(folder).listFiles();     
for (File file : list) {
    System.out.println(file + " - " + file.exists());
}
```

I get...

```
/path/to/home/.bash_history - true
/path/to/home/.CFUserTextEncoding - true
/path/to/home/.config - true
/path/to/home/.cups - true
```

Which is, obviously, far more useful.

You have to remember, Java is stupid, it doesn't know that when you specify a `String` value for a name where to look for that file, it makes an assumption based on your current location (unless you specify an absolute path of course)

Answer (score 0):

Use this file to delete (and do not prepend with `File.separator`, the parent folder is what matters):

```
fileDelete = new File( dir, file );
```

and it will work. `dir.list(filter)` only returns file names without path (e.g. directory name), and if `dir` is not the current working directory, `new File( file )` will not point to the file it was included for, `new File( dir, file )` will.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a list of files in `folder`, but this is **NOT** where you attempt to delete the files from.
BTW: is that "31052012-TPBSDERG.cache -" the actual file name???